# Como puedo recibir esta consulta en mi Activity?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Como puedo recibir esta consulta en mi Activity mediante  `Dao` -> `Repository` -> `Viewmodel` -> `Activity`

Este es mi `Dao`y la consulta es

```
@Query("SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email")
String findByEmail(String email);
```

En el momento solo sé recibir listas, pero no se como recibir una consulta con un solo valor. (como muestro a continuación)

En otro caso así recibo una consulta con una lista Livedata por medio del ViewModel median un metodo observador, pero se ejecuta cada que hay un cambio en la table, y no me sirve, quisiera poder recibir un solo dato de una consulta.

```
usuarioViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UsuarioViewModel.class);
            usuarioViewModel.getUsuarioByEmail(email).observe(this, new Observer<List<UsuarioEntity>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<UsuarioEntity> usuarioEntities) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "nombre es"+usuarioEntities.get(0).getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Y esta seria la consulta de mi `Dao` para el ejemplo anterior

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email")
LiveData<List<UsuarioEntity>> getUsuarioByEmail(String email);
```

Comment: Hola! Podrias agregar el ejemplo de como recibes listas? :D

Comment: Hola rguzman, acabo de editar mi consulta, para que veas como recibo una lista, pero cada que se actualiza se ejecuta mediante el `onChanged` entonces por ese motivo quisiera saber como recibir solo un dato en mi `activity`

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tiene que ver con el tipo de dato que estas manejando para el Observer. Podrías intentar devolver solo el usuario. Por ejemplo:

Este query devuelve solo un usuario, suponiendo que solo existe un email por usuario. Es decir en el LiveData, solo devolvemos `UsuarioEntity`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1")
LiveData<UsuarioEntity> getUsuarioByEmail(String email);
```

Luego, configuramos el observer para que reciba un solo usuario

```
usuarioViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UsuarioViewModel.class);
        usuarioViewModel.getUsuarioByEmail(email).observe(this, new Observer<UsuarioEntity>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(UsuarioEntity usuarioEntity) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "nombre : "+usuarioEntity.getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, veo que este método se usa para un `recyclerView`, pero en ese caso no, entonces el método se va ejecutar cada que se actualice esa tabla, es optimo esto para los procesos de la aplicación, o que otra forma puedo consultar solo un dato sin hacer uso de un Livedata.